# Using macro's in Project Debugger Options in Delphi project

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I'm trying to use standard defined macros like $(Platform) and $(Outputpath) when setting the debugger Host application and parameters in the Project options of a Delphi XE8 project file but they are not replaced when starting the debugger.

When using windows environment variables in macros they are replaced correctly.

So when using these settings:

```
Host Application: $(MYSRC)\SGUnitTests\bin\D22\$(Platform)\SGTestRunner_D22.exe
Parameters: $(outputpath)
Working directory: $(MYSRC)\SGUnitTests\bin\D22\$(Platform)\
```

running it results in the message

> Could not find program: "S:\Sources\SGUnnitTests\bin\D22\%Platform%\SGTestRunner_D22.exe"

As you can see the environment variable MySrc is replaced, but the macro Platform is not.

Is this a known bug? Am i doing something wrong? How can I get this to work?